# Conditional evaluation of callback arguments

Tags: javascript, callback, ecmascript-6

Recently I've been getting into the javascript ecosystem. After sometime with javascript's callbacks I started asking myself if the javascript interpreters are capable of doing conditional evaluation of callback arguments. Let's take the following two example:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

// example 1
abc.func(a, b, function (res) {
  // do something with res
});

// example 2
abc.func(a, b, function () {
  // do something
});
```

From what I understand, Javascript uses the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object to keep track of what is passed into a function. This is regardless of what the function definition is. So assuming that:

```
abc.func = function (a, b, cb) {
  // do stuff
  var res = {};
  // Expensive computation to populate res
  cb(res);
}
```

In both examples (1, 2) the `res` object will be passed to `arguments[0]`. In example 1 `res === arguments[0]` since the `res` parameter is defined.

Let's assume that computing `res` is expensive. In example 1 it's ok to go through this computation since the `res` object is used. In example 2, since the `res` object is not used, there really is no point in doing that computation. Although, since the `arguments` object needs to be populated, in both cases the computation to populate `res` is done. Is this correct ?

Assuming that's true, this seems like a (potentially) huge waste. Why compute something that's going to go out of scope and be garbage collected ? Think of all the libraries out there that use callbacks. A lot of them send multiple arguments back to the callback function, but sometimes none of them are used.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour. Essentially make the Javascript interpreter smart enough to not compute those specific variables that will turn into unused arguments ? So in example 2 the `res` object would not actually be computed since it will never actually be used.

I understand that until this point things like this were used:

```
function xyz(a, b /*, rest */)
  // use arguments to iterate over rest
}
```

So by default it makes sense to still compute those arguments. Now let's look forward to ECMAScript 2015. This will include the [`...rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) parameter to be defined. So for engines that support the new version, is there a way to enable conditional evaluation? This would make much more sense, since now there is a way to explicitly ask to evaluate and pass in all extra arguments to a function.

Comment: `res` is not being computed by the callback but rather by the function that calls the callback. So it's up to the function that calls the callback to check the callback expected parameters and compute or not the required parameters.

Comment: I'm well aware that `res` gets computed in the function that calls the callback. Sorry if the question didn't make that clear.  What part create the confusion ?

Comment: It's no confusion. Your question made it looks like you think that it makes a difference calling the callback with an extra argument that doesn't fit the function parameters, it doesn't. Populating the argument does. And you only do so because you think that the callback might use it.

Answer (score 2):

No, JavaScript is not a lazy call-by-name language. This is mostly because expressions can have side effects, and the ES standard requires them to be executed in the order the programmer expects them.

Yes, JS engines are smart. If they do detect that code does not execute side effects, and its results are not used anywhere, it just dumps them ([dead code elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination)). I'm not sure whether this works across function boundaries, I guess it doesn't, but if you are in a hot code path and the call does get inlined, it might be optimised.

So if you know that you are doing a heavy computation, you may want to make it lazy explicitly by passing a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk). In an eagerly evaluated language, this is typically simply represented by a function that takes no parameters. In your case:

```
abc.func = function (a, b, cb) {
  // do stuff
  var res = {};
  cb(() => {
    // Expensive computation to populate res
    return res;
  });
}
// example 1
abc.func(a, b, function(getRes) {
  var res = getRes();
  // do something with res
});
// example 2
abc.func(a, b, function() {
  // no heavy computation
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Using lazy evaluation was definitely in my mind while writing the question, thanks for showing me how to actually do it. Although this only works if you are the one writing the software. If you're using any other library, you're at the mercy of whatever they've done or just at a loss.

Comment: @KassymDorsel: yes, indeed you are. Although you're always free to switch the library, rewrite the library, or make a pull request, if the performance is really unacceptable. Maybe their API design is simply borked if they often do needless expensive computations.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't do that on an interpreter level, it's not feasible to determine whether or not computing a argument was dependent on computing another argument, and even if you could this would create inconsistent behaviour for the user. And because passing in variables into a function is extremely cheap, this becomes a pointless exercise.

It could be done on a functional level - if you wanted to you could pass the expected arguments of the callback as a parameter to the function, thereby augmenting the behaviour of the function based on the parameters, which is commonplace.

Comment: Passing the variable to the function may be cheap, but that is not the concern. The concern is the initial computation of the said argument in the parent function. Is it common place for function that accept callbacks to check how many arguments the callback wants?

Comment: If it's an expensive computation then yes, it is common place. Moreover, someone might provide a different function altogether that just don't populate said argument. It then falls to the programmer to choose the appropiate function.